# TextWatcher not behaving as expected

Tags: android

I have a number of EditText's and some TextView's next to them, when a field isn't filled in,  the TextView needs to be red. I have the following code to accomplish this.

```
    final TextView textSoftware = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSoftware);
    final EditText fieldSoftware = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fieldSoftware);

    fieldSoftware.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!fieldSoftware.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) { 
                textSoftware.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }else{
                textSoftware.setTextColor(Color.RED);   
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        };
    });
```

However, when I just repeat this snippet for the other fields and textviews, the else statement doesn't seem to function. It turns white like it should, but not back to red when you erase your entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if (fieldSoftware.length()<=0) { 
                textSoftware.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }else{
                textSoftware.setTextColor(Color.RED);   
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For better response use this

```
if (fieldSoftware.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) { 
       textSoftware.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}else{
       textSoftware.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
 }
```